# How to create different shape of trapezoid images using css?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website where I need to use different trapezoid shape of images. Here I am giving you that image in link:

Thanks Riccardo, Appreciate your effort.

Following are the 2 points I still need to sort it out.

This is the image that I got after implement your code.

[image]

1. Shape of the site will be skewed but not the image. The current shape is perfect but all images are also got skewed along with the shape which I don't want. I want all the images not to be shown as skewed as it is showing right now. So need guidance on that particular issue.
2. And the 2nd most important thing is about the total structure of the site. My site will be in 100% but in Container, you have given fixed height and width but I want the height and the width will be 100%.

I have tried by putting 100% width instead of current pixels but it all messed up. Here I am posting my given css. The left part of the shape is fixed, its not increasing while I am giving the widhth 30%. And the right side shape is moving far right and in between middle and right shape the container backgroup is shown which is in orange color as per the css code. And eventually I messed up all things, Here is thislink of that:

One more thing I would like to add is that Can it be possible to put 100% height on that container. Because whenever I tried to put height 100%, the whole structure get vanished. So any solution in that particular height point?

The both image issue and width height 100% issue are important for the website to function. So need your guidance on this.

Comment: Don't share the file with that service. Upload it to imgur via Stack Overflow's interface.

Comment: @alex thats a minimum 10 rep service

Comment: @RichardTingle I suspected as much. Still, RapidShare is a horrible service to share images with. Users can always manually upload to imgur and link to it (I think that's allowed).

Comment: Yes. Rapidshare is a) one of the slowest, and b) it deletes its files after 2 months, so this link will become useless. Other than that, it's not that horrible though. Lots of ads on the site, but most of the ads are for itself.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle that the original poster tried to post, but I think Stack Overflow requires that they come with code in the question itself: http://jsfiddle.net/swati712/XQNzu/.

Answer (score 0):

HTML STRUCTURE FOR REFERENCE:

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="left">
        <img src=""/>
    </span>
    <span id="middle">
        <img src=""/>
    </span>
    <span id="right"></span>
</div>
```

I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/3pqFE/2/) example for you with pure css.

Now let explain how I made it.

I take a container, set the dimension of that and the relative position.

```
#container{
    width: 600px;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

If you set the `overflow: hidden` all the element inside the container will be truncated and they can't expand outside of the parent.

After that I put 3 span in the container, they are inline element so I can't set their `width` or `height`. To do that I set their `display:` property to `inline-block`. Now I can give to the `span` a dimension.

The `span` are in a `absolute` position because I want the spans to be able to overlap.

For that after the absolute position use `z-index`.

The 3 span ids.

```
#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
    transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left img {
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg,0deg);
}
#middle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index: 3;
    border-right: 10px solid white;
    border-left: 10px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#middle img {
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    margin-left: -50px;
}
#right {
    position:absolute;
    right:-100px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:400px;
    background-color:gray;
    height:300px;
    transform:skew(-20deg,0deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(-20deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:skew(-20deg,0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index:2;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

As you can see there are the `skew` transformation for the shapes, and also the `overflow: hidden` because I don't want the `img` inside the span go outside the parent area.

When I put an `img` inside the skewed span, it take also the skew of the shape. So apply the

```
#nameofskewedcontainer img {
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
}
```

where the skew property are exactly the opposite that is applied to the span. With that I keep the img with the standard shape without skew. (try to remove that in jsfiddle demo and see)

So I hope I was clear. For everything leave a comment!

SECOND [UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/3pqFE/3/) SOLUTION:

WIDTH 100%

CSS->

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left img {
    transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
}
#middle {
    position:absolute;
    left: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index: 3;
    border-right: 10px solid white;
    border-left: 10px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#middle img {
    transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    margin-left: -50px;
}
#right {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 300px;
    transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Anyway roy, remember that in stackoverflow you can ask of something, but also you have to practice with the answers that are given to you. This is the only way you can really learn something.**

Comment: Is the  solution that you want?

Comment: I have just posted my queries regarding the same. You have done a great help till now. So I want your final guidance to sort me out of those following issues. I also given you a jsfiddle link regarding 100% width issue. And the images are got skewed along with the shape. So I want image to be not skewed like the shape.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swati712/XQNzu/   This is the jsfiddle link. Please take a look at if you have time. My site will be 100% so for that I have given 100% width. And then whole things got messed up.

Comment: Because you have to add moz-transition band transition To remove skew to img i don't added it before

Comment: We just figured that out. Now images are all shows perfectly. And hope you will give some idea how to show the whole structure in % format.