# CSS 100% width issue

Tags: html, css

Facing the issue while using 100% in the container CSS. Here I am enclosing the image where you can see the RED background color shown in the right side image.

[image: Image showing the problem with image not completely filling container]

Here I am give you all my CSS code jsfiddle link. Please take a look at and tell me what CSS I need to modify so that all that angles background (red, yellow, green) not going to show.

Total width I have given in different ID also exceeds 100% (in left I gave 39%, middle 50% and right 34%) which is total 123%. I know its wrong from my part but I couldn't find any other way to fix that design.

My computer screen resolution is 1600 to 900 and after implementing those CSS I only see the RED background in right image. But in smaller screen, as you can see in link, all other background images are showed up.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"><img  src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/c3/1f/5f/working-people-exhibit.jpg"/></div>
    <div id="middle"><img src="http://global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Health/Women%20Working.jpg"/></div>
    <div id="right"><img src="http://www.koindo.com/images/WORKING%20PEOPLE%20IMAGE.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    background-color:orange;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#left{
    position:absolute;
    left:-4%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:39%;
    background-color:red;
    height:300px;
    transform:skew(-20deg,0deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(-20deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:skew(-20deg,0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#left img{
    transform:skew(20deg,0deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(20deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:skew(20deg,0deg); /* Safari and Chrome**/ 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#middle{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:30%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    background-color:green;
    height:300px;
    transform:skew(-20deg,0deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(-20deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:skew(-20deg,0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index:2;
    border-left:10px solid white;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#middle img{
    transform:skew(20deg,0deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(20deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:skew(20deg,0deg); /* Safari and Chrome**/ 
    margin-left:-11%;   
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}
#right{
    position:absolute;
    right:-4%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:34%;
    background-color:red;
    height:300px;
    border-left:10px solid white;
    transform:skew(-20deg,0deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(-20deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:skew(-20deg,0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    z-index:3;
    overflow:hidden;

}

#right img{
    transform:skew(20deg,0deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(20deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:skew(20deg,0deg); /* Safari and Chrome**/     
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}
```

(on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swati712/XQNzu/5/)

Comment: Please read: [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code/)

Comment: here is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/swati712/XQNzu/5/

Comment: @OP: I replaced the image links with shorter url's, because they don't really add anything to the html code, but they make it harder to see the structure of the html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create different shape of trapezoid images using css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628426/how-to-create-different-shape-of-trapezoid-images-using-css)

Comment: @Riccardo: its not duplicate..if you clearly look into the 2 codes there are few modifications that has been done from my end. I analyzed your code and then changed a few. And thanks for giving me the initial help. I wanted to do that better and that's why I posted it here with different issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of the problem is thinking that your left and right divs need to be skewed while really only the middle div needs it and can be placed on top of the others.

The key to covering the middle div's corners is to put the inner div as not having `100%` width but starting 55px to the left and right, which is the width of the resulting green triangles to the left and right.

Check out this update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XQNzu/7/

I changed a number of other properties, most notably changing you img tags to divs with background images so that you can use the `background-size: cover` property to avoid changing the aspect ratio or leaving corners not covered.

The result is similar to what you had not not exact and you probably will want to do a little tweaking to get it just right for you.

Comment: Cool @roy712, well remember to mark it as an answer if it worked for you.